# Can I call a ASP .NET 2.0 WebMethod through POST request without specifying all parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, asp.net-2.0

I have methods that can accept multiple parameters and combinations of them. Without declaring a method for every possible combination of parameters, can I declare just one method with all the parameters and then check which ones have been provided?

Comment: can you provide some code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can if you specify the parameters as optional, as in

```
public static string DoSomething(string base = "DEFAULTVALUE")
{
    if (base == "DEFAULTVALUE")
    {
        // Then base was not specified.
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that it is not a feature of .net 2.0. I'm stuck with it and it's not the first problem it gives me. Thanks anyway

Comment: @mikepa88 Then the only option is to make a parent method with all parameters and one method for each combination you need

Comment: That's what I started with, but for some methods, there's many combinations and it get a bit cumbersome.

Comment: @mikepa88 It's understandable, but that's what you get using a 12 years old version

Comment: yeah... damn clients